# Ffind a special text in Word document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to find all text with format: "C " + number + (":" or ".")

Ex: "C 1:", "C 2:", "C 3:",...

in a Word Document.

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(inputFileO);

Range rngFind = wordDoc.Range();
string regex = "C [0 - 9]{ 1,3}[:.]";
while (rngFind.Find.Execute(regex))
{
    //and show what i have found here
}
```

But it is not run...
How to find them with C# interop Word?

Comment: What error are you getting? Or are you just getting no data?

Comment: Yes, i just getting no data. This code do not found anything in my Word document

Comment: [Range.Find.Execute doesn't use Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute)

Comment: You should iterate over your paragraphs and apply `Regex.Match` in each paragraphs contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values you want to retrieve are in the folloiwng format:

> Ex: "C 1:", "C 2:", "C 3:",...

Then your regex will never match. Try this instead: `C [0-9]{1,3}[:.]`

Note: I created a word document with the following lines:

```
C 134:
C 1:
C 155:
```

This code opens the word doc and applies the regex:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declare list to store lines of data from the docx file.
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        Application app = new Application();
        
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref inputFileO);
        //loop through the paragraphs in the docx file and store conents in the list.
        foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            data.Add(objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim());

        ((_Document)doc).Close();
        ((_Application)app).Quit();

        string regex = "C [0-9]{1,3}[:.]";
        //loop through the lines, write matches to console.
        //added counter
        int lineCNT = 1;
        foreach (string line in data)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(line, regex);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string key = match.Groups[0].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(key + " on line " + lineCNT);
            }
            lineCNT++;
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Console output is:

```
C 134: on line 1
C 1: on line 2
C 155: on line 3
```

See it match here: [regexr.com/59cfp](http://regexr.com/59cfp)

Comment: Hey, if my text is "C 35:" or "C 923."

Comment: Thank for your help, but your code is not run. It is not find anything, i was tested...haizzz

Comment: Ok, so the value can be 1-3 digits, answer updated.

Comment: `Range.Find.Execute` doesn't use Regex

Comment: Magnetron, can you help me

Comment: @Magnetron ah yeah, you're right. I assumed he was accessing the word doc correctly and his issue was the regex. Updating now.

Comment: @Mikael thank you. I have one more question. With your way, can i take the location of text in Word Doc?

Comment: @Mikael, no, my ideal is start position in word doc, not line in doc. It like start of range in word doc.